# Program to find all possible legal words and their scores in a Wordfeud (or Scrabble) game

Tags: c++

To anyone who doesn't know WordFeud, but is familiar with Scrabble, WordFeud is just a variation with different letter bonus placements.

The code below is complete and runnable. Given a WordFeud board and 7 letters, it will generate all words that a player can place on the board with those letters, including their scores.

Note that the dictionary used is Danish, so the words are unfamiliar to English readers.

I intended to have various algorithms to select the best word from the list of possibilities, for example, just selecting the word with the highest score, may not be the best, as it may set up your opponent to place a word with an even better score.
I want to have two bots play each other using these algorithms, and since the program goes through a lot of possibilities, performance is my main concern. Though any tips to improve the code is appreciated.

PS. Its quite a bit of code. The most important function is really `Board::allValidWords()`.
PPS. This code will be integrated with a UI which may help explain some of the choices like not just returning strings.

**Main.cpp**

```
#define _SILENCE_CXX17_CODECVT_HEADER_DEPRECATION_WARNING

#include "SquareArray.hpp"
#include "Square.hpp"
#include "Board.hpp"
#include "WordReader.hpp"

#include <set>
#include <iostream>

WF::WordReader wordReader(L"C:\\Users\\ldeir\\source\\repos\\WFCheat\\WFCheat\\Res\\fuldformsliste.csv");

int main() {
    WF::Board board;

    board.getSquare(7, 7)->setLetter('a', WF::Square::State::PLACED);
    board.getSquare(7, 8)->setLetter('b', WF::Square::State::PLACED);
    board.getSquare(7, 9)->setLetter('e', WF::Square::State::PLACED);

    std::wcout << board.toString() << std::endl;

    auto words = board.allValidWords(L"banders", &wordReader);

    for (auto word : words) {
        std::wcout << word.toString() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Letter.hpp**

```
#pragma once

namespace WF
{
    class Letter
    {
    public:
        Letter();
        Letter(wchar_t letter, unsigned int score);

        wchar_t letter() const;
        unsigned int score() const;

        void setLetter(wchar_t letter);
        void setScore(unsigned int score);

    private:
        static unsigned int getLetterScore(wchar_t letter);
        void makeLowercase();

        wchar_t m_letter;
        unsigned int m_score;
    };
}
```

**Letter.cpp**

```
#include "Letter.hpp"

namespace WF
{
    Letter::Letter() : 
        m_letter(L' '), 
        m_score(0)
    {
    }

    Letter::Letter(wchar_t letter, unsigned int score) :
        m_letter(letter), 
        m_score(score)
    {
    }

    wchar_t Letter::letter() const
    {
        return m_letter;
    }

    unsigned int Letter::score() const
    {
        return m_score;
    }

    void Letter::setLetter(wchar_t letter)
    {
        m_letter = letter;
        m_score = Letter::getLetterScore(letter);
    }

    void Letter::setScore(unsigned int score)
    {
        m_score = score;
    }

    unsigned int Letter::getLetterScore(wchar_t letter)
    {
        static constexpr int A_SCORE = 1;
        static constexpr int B_SCORE = 3;
        static constexpr int C_SCORE = 8;
        static constexpr int D_SCORE = 2;
        static constexpr int E_SCORE = 1;
        static constexpr int F_SCORE = 3;
        static constexpr int G_SCORE = 3;
        static constexpr int H_SCORE = 4;
        static constexpr int I_SCORE = 3;
        static constexpr int J_SCORE = 4;
        static constexpr int K_SCORE = 3;
        static constexpr int L_SCORE = 2;
        static constexpr int M_SCORE = 4;
        static constexpr int N_SCORE = 1;
        static constexpr int O_SCORE = 2;
        static constexpr int P_SCORE = 4;
        static constexpr int Q_SCORE = 1;
        static constexpr int R_SCORE = 1;
        static constexpr int S_SCORE = 2;
        static constexpr int T_SCORE = 2;
        static constexpr int U_SCORE = 3;
        static constexpr int V_SCORE = 4;
        static constexpr int W_SCORE = 1;
        static constexpr int X_SCORE = 8;
        static constexpr int Y_SCORE = 4;
        static constexpr int Z_SCORE = 9;
        static constexpr int Æ_SCORE = 4;
        static constexpr int Ø_SCORE = 4;
        static constexpr int Å_SCORE = 4;
        static constexpr int SCORES[29] = { A_SCORE, B_SCORE, C_SCORE, D_SCORE, E_SCORE, F_SCORE, G_SCORE, H_SCORE, I_SCORE, J_SCORE, K_SCORE, L_SCORE, M_SCORE, N_SCORE, O_SCORE, P_SCORE, Q_SCORE, R_SCORE, S_SCORE, T_SCORE, U_SCORE, V_SCORE, W_SCORE, X_SCORE, Y_SCORE, Z_SCORE, Æ_SCORE, Ø_SCORE, Å_SCORE };

        if (letter == L'æ')
        {
            return Æ_SCORE;
        }
        else if (letter == L'ø') {
            return Ø_SCORE;
        }
        else if (letter == L'å') {
            return Å_SCORE;
        }
        else {
            return SCORES[letter - L'a'];
        }
    }

    void Letter::makeLowercase()
    {
        switch (m_letter) {
        case L'A': m_letter = L'a'; break;
        case L'B': m_letter = L'b'; break;
        case L'C': m_letter = L'c'; break;
        case L'D': m_letter = L'd'; break;
        case L'E': m_letter = L'e'; break;
        case L'F': m_letter = L'f'; break;
        case L'G': m_letter = L'g'; break;
        case L'H': m_letter = L'h'; break;
        case L'I': m_letter = L'i'; break;
        case L'J': m_letter = L'j'; break;
        case L'K': m_letter = L'k'; break;
        case L'L': m_letter = L'l'; break;
        case L'M': m_letter = L'm'; break;
        case L'N': m_letter = L'n'; break;
        case L'O': m_letter = L'o'; break;
        case L'P': m_letter = L'p'; break;
        case L'Q': m_letter = L'q'; break;
        case L'R': m_letter = L'r'; break;
        case L'S': m_letter = L's'; break;
        case L'T': m_letter = L't'; break;
        case L'U': m_letter = L'u'; break;
        case L'V': m_letter = L'v'; break;
        case L'W': m_letter = L'w'; break;
        case L'X': m_letter = L'x'; break;
        case L'Y': m_letter = L'y'; break;
        case L'Z': m_letter = L'z'; break;
        case L'Æ': m_letter = L'æ'; break;
        case L'Ø': m_letter = L'ø'; break;
        case L'Å': m_letter = L'å'; break;
        default: m_letter = m_letter; break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Square.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <optional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include "Letter.hpp"

namespace WF 
{
    class Square
    {
    public:
        enum class Type {
            NORMAL,
            DOUBLE_LETTER,
            TRIPLE_LETTER,
            DOUBLE_WORD,
            TRIPLE_WORD
        };

        enum class State {
            EMPTY,
            PLACED,
            TEMPORARY_PLACED, // Used when a tile is occupied by currentplayer but not yet placed
            VIEWED // Used when the player has set a tile to be viewed using the combobox in the UI
        };

        Square(unsigned int x, unsigned int y);

        Type type() const;
        State state() const;

        void setType(Type type);

        unsigned int x() const;
        unsigned int y() const;

        void setLetter(wchar_t letter, State state);
        std::optional<Letter> letter();

        void removeLetter();
        void removeLetterIfStateIs(State state);

        // less than operator for std::set
        bool operator<(const Square& other) const;

        std::wstring toString();

    private:
        Type m_type;
        State m_state;
        Letter m_letter;
        int m_x;
        int m_y;
    };

    // This is a comparator for the set of Squares in the SquareArray.
    // By default the set would be sorted by the memory address of the Squares.
    // This comparator will sort the Squares by calling the operator< of the Square.
    // I have no idea why i can return iterators to the set without including the comparator and i dont know if this is a good idea.
    struct SquareCmp {
        bool operator()(const std::shared_ptr<Square>& lhs, const std::shared_ptr<Square>& rhs) const
        {
            return lhs->operator<(*rhs);
        }
    };
}
```

**Square.cpp**

```
#include "Square.hpp"

#include <string>

namespace WF
{
    Square::Square(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) :
        m_x(x),
        m_y(y),
        m_type(Type::NORMAL),
        m_state(State::EMPTY),
        m_letter(Letter())
    {
    }

    Square::Type Square::type() const
    {
        return m_type;
    }

    Square::State Square::state() const
    {
        return m_state;
    }

    void Square::setType(Type type)
    {
        m_type = type;
    }

    unsigned int Square::x() const 
    {
        return m_x;
    }

    unsigned int Square::y() const
    {
        return m_y;
    }

    void Square::setLetter(wchar_t letter, State state)
    {
        m_letter.setLetter(letter);
        m_state = state;
    }

    std::optional<Letter> Square::letter()
    {
        if (m_state == State::EMPTY)
        {
            return std::nullopt;
        }

        return m_letter;
    }

    void Square::removeLetter()
    {
        m_letter.setLetter(' ');
        m_state = State::EMPTY;
    }

    void Square::removeLetterIfStateIs(State state)
    {
        if (m_state == state)
        {
            removeLetter();
        }
    }

    
    bool Square::operator<(const Square& other) const
    {
        // Return true if this square is before the other in a left-to-right, top-to-bottom order
        // This function is only used when comparing squares in the same row or same column (i.e. x or y is the same)
        if (y() < other.y())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (this->y() == other.y())
        {
            return this->x() < other.x();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Given a Square with a letter, a state, a type, and x and y coordinates, return a string representation of the square
    // The string representation is a JSON object with the following properties:
    // - x: the x coordinate of the square
    // - y: the y coordinate of the square
    // - letter: the letter on the square (if any)
    // - state: the state of the square (if any)
    // - type: the type of the square (if any)
    // Example: {"x": 0, "y": 0, "letter": "A", "state": "EMPTY", "type": "NORMAL"}
    std::wstring Square::toString()
    {
        std::wstring str;
        str += L"{";
        str += L"\"x\": " + std::to_wstring(x()) + L", ";
        str += L"\"y\": " + std::to_wstring(y()) + L", ";
        if (letter() != std::nullopt)
        {
            str += L"\"letter\": \"" + std::wstring(1, letter().value().letter()) + L"\", ";
        }
        str += L"}";

        return str;
    }
}
```

**SquareArray.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <set>

#include "Square.hpp"
#include "WordSquares.hpp"

namespace WF 
{
    class SquareArray
    {
    public:
        SquareArray(Direction direction, unsigned int index);

        Direction direction();
        unsigned int index(); // The row or column index (depending on direction).
        unsigned int length(); 
        unsigned int amountOfEmptySquares();

        void addSquare(std::shared_ptr<Square> square);

        bool contains(std::shared_ptr<Square> square);
        
        bool wordAtOffsetFitsOnBoard(std::wstring word, unsigned int offset);
        void placeWordAtOffset(std::wstring word, unsigned int offset);
        void removeAllUnplaced();

        // begin and end functions
        std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>>::iterator begin();
        std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>>::iterator end();

        // WordSquares will be all the squares that are Temporaryly filled in.
        // If there are no Temporaryly filled in squares it will return an empty optional.
        // This may happen if the word that were temporarly placed on the squares were already placed on the board.
        std::optional<WordSquares> getTempPlacedWordSquares();
        std::optional<WordSquares> getFullWord();

    private:
        std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>>::iterator firstTempPlaced();
        std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>>::iterator lastTempPlaced();

        std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>, SquareCmp> m_squares;
        Direction m_direction;
        unsigned int m_index;
    };
}
```

**SquareArray.cpp**

```
#include "SquareArray.hpp"

#include <algorithm>

namespace WF
{
    SquareArray::SquareArray(Direction direction, unsigned int index) :
        m_direction(direction),
        m_index(index)
    {
    }

    Direction SquareArray::direction()
    {
        return m_direction;
    }

    unsigned int SquareArray::index()
    {
        return m_index;
    }

    unsigned int SquareArray::length()
    {
        return m_squares.size();
    }

    unsigned int SquareArray::amountOfEmptySquares()
    {
        // Return the number of empty squares in this array
        return std::count_if(m_squares.begin(), m_squares.end(), [](std::shared_ptr<Square> square) { return square->state() == Square::State::EMPTY; });
    }

    void SquareArray::addSquare(std::shared_ptr<Square> square)
    {
        m_squares.insert(square);
    }

    bool SquareArray::contains(std::shared_ptr<Square> square)
    {
        return m_squares.find(square) != m_squares.end();
    }

    bool SquareArray::wordAtOffsetFitsOnBoard(std::wstring word, unsigned int offset)
    {
        return (word.size() + offset) < m_squares.size();
    }

    void SquareArray::placeWordAtOffset(std::wstring word, unsigned int offset) // canPlaceWordAtOffset should be called before this ()
    {
        auto it = m_squares.begin();
        std::advance(it, offset);

        for (auto letter : word)
        {
            if (it->get()->state() == Square::State::EMPTY)
                it->get()->setLetter(letter, Square::State::TEMPORARY_PLACED); // TODO: Scores (probably shouldent be a parameter but just set by constructor)
            ++it;
        }
    }

    void SquareArray::removeAllUnplaced()
    {
        for (auto square : m_squares)
        {
            square->removeLetterIfStateIs(Square::State::TEMPORARY_PLACED);
        }
    }

    std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>>::iterator SquareArray::begin()
    {
        return m_squares.begin();
    }

    std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>>::iterator SquareArray::end()
    {
        return m_squares.end();
    }

    std::optional<WordSquares> SquareArray::getFullWord() {
        auto first = firstTempPlaced();
        auto last = lastTempPlaced();
        
        // If there are no squares placed, return nullopt
        if (first == m_squares.end() || last == m_squares.end())
            return std::nullopt;

        // Check if there are placed squares to the left of first and to the right of last
        while (first != m_squares.begin() && (*first)->state() == Square::State::PLACED)
        {
            --first;
        }

        while (last != m_squares.end() && (*last)->state() == Square::State::PLACED)
        {
            ++last;
        }

        return WordSquares(std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>, SquareCmp>(first, ++last), m_direction);
    }

    std::optional<WordSquares> SquareArray::getTempPlacedWordSquares()
    {
        auto first = firstTempPlaced();
        auto last = lastTempPlaced();

        if (first == m_squares.end() || last == m_squares.end())
            return std::nullopt;

        if (std::distance(first, last) < 1)
            return std::nullopt;

        return WordSquares(std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>, SquareCmp>(firstTempPlaced(), lastTempPlaced()), m_direction);
    }

    std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>>::iterator SquareArray::firstTempPlaced()
    {
        auto it = m_squares.begin();
        while (it != m_squares.end())
        {
            if ((*it)->state() == Square::State::TEMPORARY_PLACED)
                return it;
            ++it;
        }

        return m_squares.end();
    }

    std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>>::iterator SquareArray::lastTempPlaced()
    {
        auto it = m_squares.end();
        while (it != m_squares.begin())
        {
            --it;
            if ((*it)->state() == Square::State::TEMPORARY_PLACED)
                return it;
        }

        return m_squares.end();
    }
}
```

**WordSquares.hpp**

```
#pragma once

// The WordSquares class is basically a special case of SquareArray.
// It does not contain any empty squares
// For this reason it has some extra functionality, used to calculate the score of the word.

#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

#include "Square.hpp"

namespace WF
{
    enum class Direction
    {
        HORIZONTAL,
        VERTICAL
    };

    class WordSquares
    {
    public:
        WordSquares(std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>, SquareCmp> squares, Direction direction);

        unsigned int score();
        Direction direction();
        unsigned int size() const;

        // Both functions are needed here. 
        // The calculate score function is used to calculate the score of the word contained in this WordSquares.
        // The WordSquares class only has access to the squares in one line though (either horizontal or vertical).
        // The addToScore function is called from Board::isWordSquaresValidAndCalculateScore method and is used to add the score of the words in the other direction.
        void addToScore(unsigned int amount);
        unsigned int calculateScore();

        std::wstring toString();

        bool hasAnyPlacedLetters() const;

        std::set<Square>::iterator begin();
        std::set<Square>::iterator end();

        // the less than operator is used to sort the word squares by score
        bool operator<(const WordSquares& other) const;

    private:
        unsigned int combinedWordMultiplier();

        std::set<Square> m_squares;
        Direction m_direction;
        unsigned int m_score;
    };
}
```

**WordSquares.cpp**

```
#include "WordSquares.hpp"

#include <algorithm>

namespace WF
{
    WordSquares::WordSquares(std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>, SquareCmp> squares, Direction direction) :
        m_squares(),
        m_direction(direction),
        m_score(0)
    {
        for (auto square : squares)
        {
            m_squares.insert(*square);
        }
    }

    unsigned int WordSquares::score()
    {
        return m_score;
    }

    void WordSquares::addToScore(unsigned int amount)
    {
        m_score += amount;
    }

    Direction WordSquares::direction()
    {
        return m_direction;
    }

    unsigned int WordSquares::size() const
    {
        return m_squares.size();
    }

    unsigned int WordSquares::calculateScore()
    {
        unsigned int score = 0;

        for (auto square : m_squares)
        {
            if (square.state() == Square::State::PLACED)
            {
                score += square.letter().value().score();
                continue;
            }

            if (square.state() == Square::State::TEMPORARY_PLACED)
            {
                switch (square.type())
                {
                case Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER:
                    score += square.letter().value().score() * 2;
                    break;

                case Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER:
                    score += square.letter().value().score() * 3;
                    break;

                default:
                    score += square.letter().value().score();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return score * combinedWordMultiplier();
    }

    std::wstring WordSquares::toString()
    {
        std::wstring word;
        for (auto square : m_squares)
        {
            word += square.letter().value().letter();
        }
        return word;
    }

    bool WordSquares::hasAnyPlacedLetters() const
    {
        return std::find_if(m_squares.begin(), m_squares.end(), [](Square square) { return square.state() == Square::State::PLACED; }) != m_squares.end();
    }

    std::set<Square>::iterator WordSquares::begin()
    {
        return m_squares.begin();
    }

    std::set<Square>::iterator WordSquares::end()
    {
        return m_squares.end();
    }

    bool WordSquares::operator<(const WordSquares& other) const
    {
        if (m_score < other.m_score) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (m_score == other.m_score) {
            // if the scores are equal, sort by the number of placed letters
            auto placedLetters = std::count_if(m_squares.begin(), m_squares.end(), [](Square square) { return square.state() == Square::State::TEMPORARY_PLACED; });
            auto otherPlacedLetters = std::count_if(other.m_squares.begin(), other.m_squares.end(), [](Square square) { return square.state() == Square::State::TEMPORARY_PLACED; });
            
            if (placedLetters < otherPlacedLetters) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (placedLetters == otherPlacedLetters) {
                return std::lexicographical_compare(m_squares.begin(), m_squares.end(), other.m_squares.begin(), other.m_squares.end());
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    unsigned int WordSquares::combinedWordMultiplier()
    {
        unsigned int multiplier = 1;
        for (auto square : m_squares)
        {
            if (square.state() == Square::State::TEMPORARY_PLACED)
            {
                if (square.type() == Square::Type::DOUBLE_WORD) {
                    multiplier *= 2;
                }
                else if (square.type() == Square::Type::TRIPLE_WORD) {
                    multiplier *= 3;
                }
            }
        }
        return multiplier;
    }
}
```

**Board.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <set>
#include <memory>
#include <vector> 

#include "Square.hpp"
#include "SquareArray.hpp"
#include "WordSquares.hpp"
#include "WordReader.hpp"

namespace WF
{
    class Board
    {
    public:
        constexpr static int BOARD_WIDTH = 15;
        constexpr static int BOARD_HEIGHT = 15;
        constexpr static int BOARD_SIZE = BOARD_WIDTH * BOARD_HEIGHT;

        Board();

        void reset(); // Sets all squares to empty

        unsigned int calculateScore(WordSquares& word);

        std::set<WordSquares> allValidWords(std::wstring letters, WordReader* wordReader);

        std::wstring toString();

        std::shared_ptr<Square> getSquare(unsigned int x, unsigned int y);

    private:
        bool hasAtleastOneOccupiedNeighbour(std::shared_ptr<Square> square);

        bool isPlaceable(std::shared_ptr<Square> square);

        std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>> placeableSquares();

        SquareArray getSquareArray(unsigned int index, Direction direction, unsigned int start, unsigned int end);

        bool isWordSquaresValidAndCalculateScore(WordSquares& wordSquares, WordReader* wordReader);

        WordSquares getWordInDirection(std::shared_ptr<Square> square, Direction direction);

        enum class NeighborDirection
        {
            Up, 
            Down,
            Left,
            Right
        };

        bool hasOccupiedNeigbor(std::shared_ptr<Square> square, NeighborDirection direction);

        std::vector<SquareArray> getAllSquareArrays(std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>> startingSquares);
    private:

        std::array<std::array<std::shared_ptr<Square>, 15>, 15> m_boardData;
    };
}
```

**Board.cpp**

```
#include "Board.hpp"

#include <string>

namespace WF
{
    Board::Board()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_HEIGHT; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_WIDTH; ++x) {
                m_boardData[y][x] = std::make_shared<Square>(x, y);
            }
        }

        // Triple words
        m_boardData[0][4]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[0][10]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[4][0]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[4][14]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[10][0]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[10][14]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[14][4]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[14][10]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_WORD);

        // Double words
        m_boardData[2][2]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[2][12]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[3][7]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[4][4]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[4][10]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[7][3]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[7][11]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[10][4]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[10][10]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[11][7]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[12][2]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_WORD);
        m_boardData[12][12]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_WORD);

        // Triple letters
        m_boardData[0][0]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[0][14]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[1][5]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[1][9]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[3][3]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[3][11]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[5][1]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[5][5]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[5][9]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[5][13]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[9][1]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[9][5]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[9][9]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[9][13]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[11][3]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[11][11]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[13][5]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[13][9]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[14][0]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[14][14]->setType(Square::Type::TRIPLE_LETTER);

        // Double letters
        m_boardData[0][7]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[1][1]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[1][13]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[2][6]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[2][8]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[4][6]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[4][8]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[6][2]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[6][4]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[6][10]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[6][12]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[7][0]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[7][14]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[8][2]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[8][4]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[8][10]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[8][12]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[10][6]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[10][8]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[12][6]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[12][8]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[13][1]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[13][13]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
        m_boardData[14][7]->setType(Square::Type::DOUBLE_LETTER);
    }

    void Board::reset()
    {
        for (auto& col : m_boardData) {
            for (auto& square : col) {
                square->removeLetter();
            }
        }
    }

    unsigned int Board::calculateScore(WordSquares& word)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    bool Board::hasOccupiedNeigbor(std::shared_ptr<Square> square, NeighborDirection direction)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
        case WF::Board::NeighborDirection::Up:
            if (square->y() != 0) {
                if (m_boardData[square->y() - 1][square->x()]->state() == Square::State::PLACED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;
        case WF::Board::NeighborDirection::Down:
            if (square->y() != BOARD_HEIGHT - 1) {
                if (m_boardData[square->y() + 1][square->x()]->state() == Square::State::PLACED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;
        case WF::Board::NeighborDirection::Left:
            if (square->x() != 0) {
                if (m_boardData[square->y()][square->x() - 1]->state() == Square::State::PLACED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;
        case WF::Board::NeighborDirection::Right:
            if (square->x() != BOARD_WIDTH - 1) {
                if (m_boardData[square->y()][square->x() + 1]->state() == Square::State::PLACED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    WordSquares Board::getWordInDirection(std::shared_ptr<Square> square, Direction direction)
    {
        std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>, SquareCmp> wordSquares;
        wordSquares.insert(square);
        std::shared_ptr<Square> currentSquare = square;
        if (direction == Direction::HORIZONTAL) {
            while (hasOccupiedNeigbor(currentSquare, NeighborDirection::Left)) {
                currentSquare = m_boardData[currentSquare->y()][currentSquare->x() - 1];
                wordSquares.insert(currentSquare);
            }

            currentSquare = square;

            while (hasOccupiedNeigbor(currentSquare, NeighborDirection::Right)) {
                currentSquare = m_boardData[currentSquare->y()][currentSquare->x() + 1];
                wordSquares.insert(currentSquare);
            }
        }
        else {
            while (hasOccupiedNeigbor(currentSquare, NeighborDirection::Up)) {
                currentSquare = m_boardData[currentSquare->y() - 1][currentSquare->x()];
                wordSquares.insert(currentSquare);
            }

            currentSquare = square;

            while (hasOccupiedNeigbor(currentSquare, NeighborDirection::Down)) {
                currentSquare = m_boardData[currentSquare->y() + 1][currentSquare->x()];
                wordSquares.insert(currentSquare);
            }
        }

        return WordSquares(wordSquares, direction);
    }

    // This function is used to check if the word squares are valid and calculate the score
    // The reason for combining these two is that all the steps invloved with checking if the word squares are valid is also needed to calculate the score
    // Thus performance is vastly improved as this function is the most performance critical function in the entire program
    bool Board::isWordSquaresValidAndCalculateScore(WordSquares& wordSquares, WordReader* wordReader)
    {
        bool foundPlacedSquare = false;

        if (!wordReader->contains(wordSquares.toString())) {
            return false;
        }

        wordSquares.addToScore(wordSquares.calculateScore());

        for (auto& square : wordSquares) {
            if (wordSquares.direction() == Direction::HORIZONTAL) {
                auto word = getWordInDirection(std::make_shared<Square>(square), Direction::VERTICAL);
                foundPlacedSquare = word.hasAnyPlacedLetters();
                if (word.size() > 1) {
                    if (!wordReader->contains(word.toString())) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    wordSquares.addToScore(word.calculateScore());
                }
            }
            else {
                auto word = getWordInDirection(std::make_shared<Square>(square), Direction::HORIZONTAL);
                foundPlacedSquare = word.hasAnyPlacedLetters();
                if (word.size() > 1) {
                    if (!wordReader->contains(word.toString())) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    wordSquares.addToScore(word.calculateScore());
                }
            }
        }

        if (!foundPlacedSquare) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    std::set<WordSquares> Board::allValidWords(std::wstring letters, WordReader* wordReader)
    {
        std::set<WordSquares> validWords;

        auto words = wordReader->findAllPossiblePermuatations(letters);
        auto wordArrays = getAllSquareArrays(placeableSquares());
        
        for (auto wordArray : wordArrays) {
            for (auto word : words) {
                for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.length() - word.size(); ++i) {
                    if (wordArray.wordAtOffsetFitsOnBoard(word, i)) { // Word can be placed in theory
                        wordArray.placeWordAtOffset(word, i);
                        auto wordSquares = wordArray.getFullWord();
                        if (wordSquares.has_value()) {
                            if (isWordSquaresValidAndCalculateScore(wordSquares.value(), wordReader)) {
                                validWords.insert(wordSquares.value());
                            }
                        }
                        wordArray.removeAllUnplaced();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return validWords;
    }

    std::wstring Board::toString()
    {
        std::wstring result;
        for (auto col : m_boardData) {
            for (auto square : col) {
                if (square->letter().has_value()) {
                    result += square->letter().value().letter();
                    result += L" ";
                } else {
                    result += L"* ";
                }
            }
            result += L"\n";
        }
        return result;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Square> Board::getSquare(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
    {
        return m_boardData[y][x];
    }

    bool Board::hasAtleastOneOccupiedNeighbour(std::shared_ptr<Square> square)
    {
        if (hasOccupiedNeigbor(square, NeighborDirection::Up)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (hasOccupiedNeigbor(square, NeighborDirection::Down)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (hasOccupiedNeigbor(square, NeighborDirection::Left)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (hasOccupiedNeigbor(square, NeighborDirection::Right)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool Board::isPlaceable(std::shared_ptr<Square> square)
    {
        // A square is placeable if it is empty and has at least one occupied neighbour or if it is the middle square and is empty
        if (square->state() == Square::State::EMPTY) {
            if (square->x() == 7 && square->y() == 7) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return hasAtleastOneOccupiedNeighbour(square);
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>> Board::placeableSquares()
    {
        std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>> placeableSquares;

        for (auto col : m_boardData) {
            for (auto square : col) {
                if (isPlaceable(square)) {
                    placeableSquares.insert(square);
                }
            }
        }

        return placeableSquares;
    }

    SquareArray Board::getSquareArray(unsigned int index, Direction direction, unsigned int start, unsigned int end)
    {
        SquareArray squareArray(direction, index);

        if (direction == Direction::HORIZONTAL) {
            for (unsigned int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                squareArray.addSquare(m_boardData[index][i]);
            }
        }
        else {
            for (unsigned int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                squareArray.addSquare(m_boardData[i][index]);
            }
        }

        return squareArray;
    }

    std::vector<SquareArray> Board::getAllSquareArrays(std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>> startingSquares)
    {
        std::set<std::shared_ptr<Square>> startingSquaresCopy(startingSquares); // Copy the set so we can remove squares as we go

        std::vector<SquareArray> horizontalSquareArrays;

        // First check rows
        for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_HEIGHT; ++col) {
            for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_WIDTH; ++row) {
                auto square = m_boardData[col][row];
                if (startingSquaresCopy.find(square) == startingSquaresCopy.end()) {
                    continue;
                }

                auto start = std::max(row - 7, 0);
                auto end = std::min(row + 7, BOARD_WIDTH - 1);
                auto squareArray = getSquareArray(col, Direction::HORIZONTAL, start, end);

                // Remove the squares in this square array from the starting squares set
                for (auto square : squareArray) {
                    startingSquaresCopy.erase(square);
                }

                horizontalSquareArrays.push_back(squareArray);

                row = end; // Skip to the end of the square array

                if (startingSquaresCopy.empty()) {
                    col = BOARD_HEIGHT; // Break out of the outer loop
                }
            }
        }

        startingSquaresCopy = startingSquares; // Reset the starting squares set
        std::vector<SquareArray> verticalSquareArrays;

        // Now check columns
        for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_WIDTH; ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < BOARD_HEIGHT; ++col) {
                auto square = m_boardData[col][row];
                if (startingSquaresCopy.find(square) == startingSquaresCopy.end()) {
                    continue; // No starting squares on this column
                }

                auto start = std::max(col - 7, 0);
                auto end = std::min(col + 7, BOARD_HEIGHT - 1);
                auto squareArray = getSquareArray(row, Direction::VERTICAL, start, end);

                // Remove the squares in this square array from the starting squares set
                for (auto square : squareArray) {
                    startingSquaresCopy.erase(square);
                }

                verticalSquareArrays.push_back(squareArray);

                col = end; // Skip to the end of the square array

                if (startingSquaresCopy.empty()) {
                    row = BOARD_WIDTH; // Break out of the outer loop
                }
            }
        }

        // Combine the horizontal and vertical square arrays
        horizontalSquareArrays.insert(horizontalSquareArrays.end(), verticalSquareArrays.begin(), verticalSquareArrays.end());

        return horizontalSquareArrays;
    }
}
```

**WordReader.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unordered_set>

#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

namespace util {
    wchar_t as_lowercase(wchar_t c);
}

namespace WF {
    class WordReader
    {
        std::vector<wchar_t> allLetters = { {
                L'a', L'b', L'c', L'd', L'e', L'f', L'g', L'h', L'i', L'j',
                L'k', L'l', L'm', L'n', L'o', L'p', L'r', L's', L't', L'u',
                L'v', L'x', L'y', L'z', L'æ', L'ø', L'å'
            } };

    public:
        WordReader(const std::wstring& filename);

        std::unordered_set<std::wstring> getWords();

        bool contains(std::wstring word) const;

        std::vector<std::wstring> findAllPossiblePermuatations(std::wstring word);

    private:
        std::vector<std::wstring> excludedWords = {
            {
                L"chi",
                L"chiet",
                L"chieer",
                L"chier",
                L"chierne"

                L"nn",

            }
        };

        bool validateWord(std::wstring word);

        std::vector<std::wstring> wordHas1Star(std::wstring letters);

        std::vector<std::wstring> wordHas2Stars(std::wstring letters);

        std::vector<std::wstring> allWordsFormableByMutatingLetters(std::wstring letters);

        std::vector<std::wstring> allWordsFormableByRemovingLetters(std::wstring letters);

        // The readWords function reads the words from the file and stores them in a set
        // Each line of the file contains 3 strings separated by a ';' 
        // We only want to store the string in between the first and second ';'
        // For example after reading the following line:
        // handel;handel;sb.
        // handel; handlen; sb.
        // handel; handelen; sb.
        // handel; handlens; sb.
        // handel; handelens; sb.
        // handel; handels; sb.
        // handel; handlerne; sb.
        // handel; handlernes; sb.
        // handel; handler; sb.
        // handel; handlers; sb.
        // The set should contain the following words:
        // handel, handelen, handelens, handels, handlerne, handler, handlers

        void readWords(const std::wstring& filename);

        std::unordered_set<std::wstring> m_words;
    };
}
```

**WordReader.cpp**

```
#include "WordReader.hpp"

namespace WF
{
    WordReader::WordReader(const std::wstring& filename) {
        readWords(filename);
    }

    std::unordered_set<std::wstring> WordReader::getWords() {
        return m_words;
    }

    bool WordReader::contains(std::wstring word) const {
        auto at = m_words.find(word);
        return at != m_words.end();
    }

    std::vector<std::wstring> WordReader::findAllPossiblePermuatations(std::wstring word) {
        return allWordsFormableByMutatingLetters(word);
        //return allWordsFormableByRemovingLetters(word);
    }

    // The validate word should return true on the following conditions:
    // 1. The word contains no spaces
    // 2. The word contains no special wchar_tacters
    // 3. The word contains no numbers
    // 4. The word does not contain the letter 'q'
    // 5. The word does not contain the letter 'w'
    bool WordReader::validateWord(std::wstring word) {
        return word.find(L' ') == std::wstring::npos &&
            word.find_first_of(L"0123456789") == std::wstring::npos &&
            word.find_first_of(L"!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{};':\",./<>?\\|") == std::wstring::npos &&
            word.find_first_of(L"qw") == std::wstring::npos &&
            std::find(excludedWords.begin(), excludedWords.end(), word) == excludedWords.end();
    }

    std::vector<std::wstring> WordReader::wordHas1Star(std::wstring letters) {
        std::unordered_set<std::wstring> validWords;

        for (wchar_t letter : allLetters) {
            auto lettersCopy = letters;
            std::replace(lettersCopy.begin(), lettersCopy.end(), L'*', letter);
            auto validWordsWithLetter = allWordsFormableByMutatingLetters(lettersCopy);
            validWords.insert(validWordsWithLetter.begin(), validWordsWithLetter.end());
            lettersCopy = letters;
        }

        return std::vector<std::wstring>(validWords.begin(), validWords.end());
    }

    std::vector<std::wstring> WordReader::wordHas2Stars(std::wstring letters) {
        std::unordered_set<std::wstring> validWords;

        for (wchar_t letter1 : allLetters) {
            for (wchar_t letter2 : allLetters) {
                auto lettersCopy = letters;
                lettersCopy.replace(lettersCopy.find(L'*'), 1, 1, letter1);
                lettersCopy.replace(lettersCopy.find(L'*'), 1, 1, letter2);
                auto validWordsWithLetter = allWordsFormableByMutatingLetters(lettersCopy);
                validWords.insert(validWordsWithLetter.begin(), validWordsWithLetter.end());
                lettersCopy = letters;
            }
        }

        return std::vector<std::wstring>(validWords.begin(), validWords.end());
    }

    std::vector<std::wstring> WordReader::allWordsFormableByMutatingLetters(std::wstring letters) {
        std::wstring lettersCopy = letters;

        int startCount = std::count(letters.begin(), letters.end(), L'*');
        if (startCount == 1) {
            return wordHas1Star(letters);
        }
        else if (startCount == 2) {
            return wordHas2Stars(letters);
        }

        std::sort(lettersCopy.begin(), lettersCopy.end());
        std::unordered_set<std::wstring> validWords;
        do {
            if (contains((lettersCopy)))
                validWords.insert(lettersCopy);

            auto lettersCopyCopy = lettersCopy;
            do {
                lettersCopyCopy.pop_back();
                if (contains((lettersCopyCopy)))
                    validWords.insert(lettersCopyCopy);
            } while (lettersCopyCopy.size() > 0);

        } while (std::next_permutation(lettersCopy.begin(), lettersCopy.end()));

        std::vector<std::wstring> validWordsVector;
        validWordsVector.insert(validWordsVector.end(), validWords.begin(), validWords.end());

        return validWordsVector;
    }

    std::vector<std::wstring> WordReader::allWordsFormableByRemovingLetters(std::wstring letters) {
        std::vector<std::wstring> validWords;
        auto formable = allWordsFormableByMutatingLetters(letters);
        validWords.insert(validWords.end(), formable.begin(), formable.end());

        // Find all unique letters in the word
        // For each letter, remove it from the word and check if the word is valid
        // If it is, add it to the list of valid words
        std::set<wchar_t> uniqueLetters;
        for (auto letter : letters) {
            uniqueLetters.insert(letter);
        }

        for (auto letter : uniqueLetters) {
            std::wstring copy = letters;
            copy.erase(std::remove(copy.begin(), copy.end(), letter), copy.end());
            auto formable = allWordsFormableByMutatingLetters(copy);
            validWords.insert(validWords.end(), formable.begin(), formable.end());
        }

        /*
        do {
            letters.pop_back();
            auto formable2 = allWordsFormableByMutatingLetters(letters);
            validWords.insert(validWords.end(), formable2.begin(), formable2.end());
        } while (letters.size() > 0);
        */


        return validWords;
    }

    void WordReader::readWords(const std::wstring& filename)
    {
        std::wifstream file(filename);
        const std::locale empty_locale = std::locale::empty();
        typedef std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> converter_type;
        const converter_type* converter = new converter_type;
        const std::locale utf8_locale = std::locale(empty_locale, converter);
        file.imbue(utf8_locale);
        std::wstring line;
        while (std::getline(file, line)) {
            // Retrieve the substring between the first and second ';'
            if (line.find(L"prop.") != std::wstring::npos) {
                continue; // Exclude place names
            }

            auto word = line.substr(line.find_first_of(L';') + 1, line.find_last_of(L';') - line.find_first_of(L';') - 1);

            std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(),
                [](wchar_t c) { return util::as_lowercase(c); });

            if (validateWord(word)) {
                m_words.insert(word);
            }
        }
        std::cout << "done\n";
    }
} 

wchar_t util::as_lowercase(wchar_t c) {
    switch (c) {
    case L'A': return L'a';
    case L'B': return L'b';
    case L'C': return L'c';
    case L'D': return L'd';
    case L'E': return L'e';
    case L'F': return L'f';
    case L'G': return L'g';
    case L'H': return L'h';
    case L'I': return L'i';
    case L'J': return L'j';
    case L'K': return L'k';
    case L'L': return L'l';
    case L'M': return L'm';
    case L'N': return L'n';
    case L'O': return L'o';
    case L'P': return L'p';
    case L'Q': return L'q';
    case L'R': return L'r';
    case L'S': return L's';
    case L'T': return L't';
    case L'U': return L'u';
    case L'V': return L'v';
    case L'W': return L'w';
    case L'X': return L'x';
    case L'Y': return L'y';
    case L'Z': return L'z';
    case L'Æ': return L'æ';
    case L'Ø': return L'ø';
    case L'Å': return L'å';
    default: return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't have access to your dictionary file, I used [this one](https://github.com/zeisler/scrabble/blob/master/db/dictionary.csv). I was able to compile the project on C++17. Some ideas:

- Check if your dictionary actually opens. This can make debugging easier across devices (see **Wordreader.cpp**).
- You can clean up `Letter.hpp` and `Letter.cpp` by using a `switch` statement with `returns` for scoring and sending letters to lowercase form (see **Letter.cpp** and **Letter.hpp**).
- There is a lot of square copying going on in `Board.cpp`. I recommend you temporarily place letters directly on the board, check directly on the board, and then undo the temporary placement. A useful abstraction might be a `Move` class: essentially a vector of coordinates / letters to place. In real life, this would be something like "If I play the move [A at (10, 10), B at (10, 11), C at (10, 12), C at (10, 13)], I'll get 20 points. Or I could play [Q at (5, 5)] and get 17 points." `allValidMoves` might be a better name than `allValidWords` if you go down that path; it could return a `vector` of `tuples` where each tuple is a `Move` and its score. Then your bots could just select the move with the highest score (and perhaps even do some minimax by guessing what tiles the opponent has).
- You might want to change `allWordsFormableByMutatingLetters` in `WordReader.cpp` to return a set.

**Wordreader.cpp**

```cpp
void WordReader::readWords(const std::wstring &filename)
{
    std::wifstream file(filename);
    if (!file)
        std::cout << "FAILED TO OPEN\n";
    const std::locale empty_locale = std::locale::empty();
    // ...
}
```

**Letter.hpp**

```cpp
class Letter
{
public:
    Letter();
    Letter(wchar_t letter);

    wchar_t letter() const;
    unsigned int score() const;

    void setLetter(wchar_t letter);

private:
    static unsigned int letterToScore(wchar_t letter);
    static wchar_t letterToLowercase(wchar_t letter);
    wchar_t m_letter;
    unsigned int m_score;
};
```

**Letter.cpp**

```
Letter::Letter() :
    m_letter(L' '),
    m_score(letterToScore(L' '))
{
}

Letter::Letter(wchar_t letter) :
    m_letter(letter),
    m_score(letterToScore(letter))
{
}

wchar_t Letter::letter() const
{
    return m_letter;
}

unsigned int Letter::score() const
{
    return m_score;
}

void Letter::setLetter(wchar_t letter)
{
    m_letter = letter;
    m_score = letterToScore(letter);
}

unsigned int Letter::letterToScore(wchar_t letter)
{
    switch (letter) {
        case L'a': return 1;
        case L'b': return 3;
        case L'c': return 8;
        case L'd': return 2;
        case L'e': return 1;
        case L'f': return 3;
        case L'g': return 3;
        case L'h': return 4;
        case L'i': return 3;
        case L'j': return 4;
        case L'k': return 3;
        case L'l': return 2;
        case L'm': return 4;
        case L'n': return 1;
        case L'o': return 2;
        case L'p': return 4;
        case L'q': return 1;
        case L'r': return 1;
        case L's': return 2;
        case L't': return 2;
        case L'U': return 3;
        case L'V': return 4;
        case L'W': return 1;
        case L'X': return 8;
        case L'Y': return 4;
        case L'Z': return 9;
        case L'Æ': return 4;
        case L'Ø': return 4;
        case L'Å': return 4;
        default: return -1; // indicate something's wrong
    }
}

wchar_t Letter::letterToLowercase(wchar_t letter)
{
    switch (letter) {
        case L'A': return L'a';
        case L'B': return L'b';
        case L'C': return L'c';
        case L'D': return L'd';
        case L'E': return L'e';
        case L'F': return L'f';
        case L'G': return L'g';
        case L'H': return L'h'; 
        case L'I': return L'i'; 
        case L'J': return L'j'; 
        case L'K': return L'k'; 
        case L'L': return L'l'; 
        case L'M': return L'm'; 
        case L'N': return L'n'; 
        case L'O': return L'o'; 
        case L'P': return L'p'; 
        case L'Q': return L'q'; 
        case L'R': return L'r'; 
        case L'S': return L's'; 
        case L'T': return L't'; 
        case L'U': return L'u';
        case L'V': return L'v'; 
        case L'W': return L'w';
        case L'X': return L'x'; 
        case L'Y': return L'y';
        case L'Z': return L'z';
        case L'Æ': return L'æ';
        case L'Ø': return L'ø';
        case L'Å': return L'å';
        default: return letter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Especially the Move class idea might indeed be a major performance boost.

Comment: Happy to! Btw I just realized you might need an extra switch case for spaces if you use the suggested Letter.cpp.